# Play developer console “An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later.” in translations

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

Whenever I try to change the default translation of my app in the Google Play Console I get a "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."

It only happens when changing the default translation language, any other change in the translations is ok. I can add new languages and so and save without a problem.

Of course, I'm working on the new beta console https://play.google.com/console

Comment: Report the issue directly on the Play Console by filing feedback on the site directly explaining the steps taken.